# Find all the IP Addresses behind any dns

Tags: bash, dns, dig

I am trying to find all the IP address of DNS .
I tried with dig and nslookup but they return IP address which are up and listening .

I want to find all the IPs configured with DNS, whether listening or not . This will help to identify if any backened servers down behind LB and want to do this using one of linux server.

I tried

```
dig dns +short
```

Comment: "I am trying to find **all the IP address of DNS**" Are you aware that there are billions of IP addresses? Luckily, I don't think there is a way to retrieve all that. If you want the records stored in a specific DNS server, a zone transfer might be your solution. This can be done with `dig` **if the DNS server allows it**. Tutorials are [found on the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=dig+zone+transfer&ia=web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean all IP addresses that belong to a particular name, you can try something like `dig(1)`:

```
$ dig -t A google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-RH <<>> -t A google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62945
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.101
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.138
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.139
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.113
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.100
google.com.     212 IN  A   64.233.186.102

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed May 19 23:43:09 -04 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
```

The `-t A` asks for `A` records (i.e., IPv4 addresses). With `-t AAAA`  you ask for IPv6 addresses. Mild massaging (delete lines starting with `;` and blank lines) gets you exactly what you want.

The (deprecated for quite some time) `host(1)` command gives similar information, in a slightly more human-readable format.

Comment: Thank you so much , this worked like charm.